# How can I read an Excel file using Zend framework?

Tags: php, excel, zend-framework

How can I read an Excel file using Zend framework?

Comment: Do you mean a native Excel file (in which case, what version of Excel) or a CSV file?

Answer (score 6):

Try PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) you can  write to and read from different file formats, like Excel 2007, PDF, HTML,

Answer (score 1):

There is no library in Zend Framework (currently v1.10) which can read or write Microsoft Excel files. There is only a [Zend_Service to read Google Spreadsheets](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html). You can use PHPExcel like Lucas suggested or use the PEAR package. Because Zend Framework is a glue framework, you can use both side by side with ZF.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly good article on this precise subject within the Zend developer zone - "[Reading and Writing Spreadsheets with PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3336)".

That said, you're likely to need some additional PEAR modules, although that's a fairly low entry requirement it has to be said.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHPExcel, here is something to [get you started](http://www.oshuamoreno.com/2009/10/phpexcel-read-excel-from-lamp/)

The only other resources I am using at the moment are its documentation. Not much info on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Spreadsheets data API allows client applications to view and update Spreadsheets content in the form of Google data API feeds. Your client application can request a list of a user's spreadsheets, edit or delete content in an existing Spreadsheets worksheet, and query the content in an existing Spreadsheets worksheet.